# 2_deploy_contracts question, about test records

Tags: solidity, truffle

With the below i'm deploying and then setting some test records.  However when I test it doesn't seem to see these records. [TESTING OUTPUT](https://www.screencast.com/t/3d5AFlADvXmM)
ignore # variation as i hadn't updated it in the test, it still returns 0 when it should return 4 now (i believe).

[Repository link in case you want to see something else](https://github.com/shaddow1201/CredentialVerify)

Test function:

```
/**
* @dev Checks Valid CredentialOrg Credential Count, checks if inital conditions are correct from migration.
*/
function testSelectValidOrgCredentialCount() public {

    address contractOwner = credentialFactory.getOwner();
    uint256 testVal = uint256(credentialFactory.selectOrgCredentialCount(contractOwner));
    uint256 expected = 4;
    Assert.equal(testVal, expected, "Expected Credential Count (4)");
}
```

create function call:

```
/**
* @dev allows credentialing Orgs to create new credentials
* @param _credentialLevel Credential Level
* @param _credentialTitle CredentialTitle
* @param _credentialDivision Credential Division
* @return insertStatus - true false if insert happened.
*/
function createCredential(string _credentialLevel, string _credentialTitle, string _credentialDivision, address _credentialOrgAddress) 
public onlyOwner
returns (bool insertStatus)
{
    emit CredentialFactoryActivity(msg.sender, _credentialTitle, "New Credential Add (ATTEMPT)");
    insertStatus = false;
    require(bytes(_credentialLevel).length > 0 && bytes(_credentialLevel).length < 50, "createCredential - Level length problem");
    require(bytes(_credentialTitle).length > 0 && bytes(_credentialTitle).length < 70, "createCredential - Title length problem");
    require(bytes(_credentialDivision).length >= 0 && bytes(_credentialDivision).length < 50, "createCredential - Division length problem");
    uint32 position = uint32(orgAddressToCredentials[_credentialOrgAddress].push(Credential(_credentialOrgAddress, _credentialLevel, _credentialTitle, _credentialDivision, uint32(block.timestamp))));
    if(position > 0){
        insertStatus = true;
        orgAddressToCredentialTotalCount[_credentialOrgAddress] = orgAddressToCredentialTotalCount[_credentialOrgAddress].add(1);
        emit CredentialFactoryActivity(_credentialOrgAddress, _credentialTitle, "New Credential Add (SUCCCESS)");
    } else {
        emit CredentialFactoryActivity(_credentialOrgAddress, _credentialTitle, "New Credential Add (FAILED)");
    }
}
```

it should be a simple retrieval call,

```
/**
* @dev allows checking of CredentialCount of a CredentialOrg
* @param _credentialOrgAddress Address of Credential Org
* @return returnCredentialCount - returns count of credentials of org.
*/
function selectOrgCredentialCount(address _credentialOrgAddress)
public view 
returns (uint32 returnCredentialCount)
{
    returnCredentialCount = orgAddressToCredentialTotalCount[_credentialOrgAddress];
    return (returnCredentialCount);
}
```

and here is the deploy scripting:

```
var SafeMath32 = artifacts.require("./SafeMath32.sol");
var CredentialOrgFactory = artifacts.require("CredentialOrgFactory");  
var CredentialFactory = artifacts.require("CredentialFactory");        
var ApplicantFactory = artifacts.require("ApplicantFactory");          
var ProcessApplicants = artifacts.require("ProcessApplicants");

module.exports = async function(deployer, accounts) {
  let safeMathInst, aInst, bInst, cInst, dInst;

  await Promise.all([
    deployer.deploy(SafeMath32),
    deployer.deploy(CredentialOrgFactory),
    deployer.deploy(CredentialFactory),
    deployer.deploy(ApplicantFactory),
    deployer.deploy(ProcessApplicants),
    deployer.link(SafeMath32,[CredentialOrgFactory,CredentialFactory,ApplicantFactory])
]);

instances = await Promise.all([
SafeMath32.deployed(),
CredentialOrgFactory.deployed(),
CredentialFactory.deployed(),
ApplicantFactory.deployed(),
ProcessApplicants.deployed(),
])

aInst = instances[1];
bInst = instances[2];
cInst = instances[3];
dInst = instances[4];

results = await Promise.all([
// Generate a base record
console.log("StartRec Creation"),
console.log("CredentialOrg Recs, owner, address of CredentialFactory, ApplicantFactory, and ProcessApplicants"),
aInst.createCredentialOrg("INITRECORD", "BASE INIT RECORD", 0x5a186B7FeC36909678211F69beB67EC3b1E4fFBB),
// Grant access to all contracts (for isCredentialOrg)  
// this doesn't quite acomplish what i'm trying to get done... as modifer onlyBy(msg.sender) still fails..
aInst.createCredentialOrg("CREDENTIAL", "CREDENTIALFACTORY", bInst.address),
aInst.createCredentialOrg("APPLICANT", "APPLICANTFACTORY", cInst.address),
aInst.createCredentialOrg("PROCESS", "PROCESSAPPLICANTS", dInst.address),

// Set Address of bInst so it can point at aInst
console.log("setAddress CredentialFactory: for CredentialOrgFactory"),
bInst.setAddress(aInst.address),
console.log("create a base set of credentials for testing"),
bInst.createCredential("Credential1", "AAAA", "AAAAAA", 0x5a186B7FeC36909678211F69beB67EC3b1E4fFBB),
bInst.createCredential("Credential2", "BBBB", "BBBBBB", 0x5a186B7FeC36909678211F69beB67EC3b1E4fFBB),
bInst.createCredential("Credential3", "CCCC", "CCCCCC", 0x5a186B7FeC36909678211F69beB67EC3b1E4fFBB),
bInst.createCredential("Credential4", "DDDD", "DDDDDD", 0x5a186B7FeC36909678211F69beB67EC3b1E4fFBB),

// Set Address of cInst so it can point at aInst
console.log("setAddress ApplicantFactory: for CredentialOrgFactory"),
cInst.setAddress(aInst.address),
console.log("insert 5 Applicant Records, for testing."),
cInst.createApplicant(0x5a186B7FeC36909678211F69beB67EC3b1E4fFBB, "123456781", "987654321", "TESTAPPLICANT1", "TESTAPPLICANT1"),
cInst.createApplicant(0x5a186B7FeC36909678211F69beB67EC3b1E4fFBB, "123456782", "987654322", "TESTAPPLICANT2", "TESTAPPLICANT2"),
cInst.createApplicant(0x5a186B7FeC36909678211F69beB67EC3b1E4fFBB, "123456783", "987654323", "TESTAPPLICANT3", "TESTAPPLICANT3"),
cInst.createApplicant(0x5a186B7FeC36909678211F69beB67EC3b1E4fFBB, "123456784", "987654324", "TESTAPPLICANT4", "TESTAPPLICANT4"),
cInst.createApplicant(0x5a186B7FeC36909678211F69beB67EC3b1E4fFBB, "123456785", "987654325", "TESTAPPLICANT5", "TESTAPPLICANT5"),

// Set Address of dInst so it can point at aInst, bInst, and cInst
dInst.setAddress(aInst.address, bInst.address, cInst.address)
]);

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing quotes around addresses in your JavaScript. E.g. this line:

```
bInst.createCredential("Credential1", "AAAA", "AAAAAA", 0x5a186B7FeC36909678211F69beB67EC3b1E4fFBB),
```

needs to be this:

```
bInst.createCredential("Credential1", "AAAA", "AAAAAA", "0x5a186B7FeC36909678211F69beB67EC3b1E4fFBB"),
```

(This is true throughout your deployment script.)

Comment: thanks!  that explains some varying results, moving forward again!